# Implementing im2col in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I wish to implement an operation similar to 2D convolution in TensorFlow. As per my understanding, the most common approach to implementing convolution is by first applying an `im2col` operation to the image (see [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv) - subsection "*Implementation as Matrix Multiplication*") - an operation that transforms an image into a 2D matrix with individual "chunks" of the image to which the kernel is applied as flattened columns.

In other words, this excerpt from the above linked resource explains what `im2col` does nicely:

> [...] For example, if the input is [227x227x3] *(in the format height x width x n_channels)* and it is to be convolved with 11x11x3 filters at stride 4, then we would take [11x11x3] blocks of pixels in the input and stretch each block into a column vector of size 11*11*3 = 363. Iterating this process in the input at stride of 4 gives (227-11)/4+1 = 55 locations along both width and height, leading to an output matrix `X_col` of `im2col` of size [363 x 3025], where every column is a stretched out receptive field and there are 55*55 = 3025 of them in total. Note that since the receptive fields overlap, every number in the input volume may be duplicated in multiple distinct columns.

As I understand from the [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d), that is what's done internally with `tf.nn.conv2d` as well.

Now, I would like to implement said `im2col` operation in TensorFlow separately (as I wish to have access to this intermediary result). As this involves copying of values in a non-trivial way, how would I build a relatively efficient computational graph for this operation myself? Similarly, how would one implement the reverse operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do this using [`extract_image_patches`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/extract_image_patches).

This function puts each `filter_size x filter_size` patch of the image into the depth yielding a `[batch_size, height, width, 9]` tensor.

To compare against `tf.nn.conv2d` you can implement the Sobel operator for images

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

image = np.arange(10 * 10 * 1).reshape(1, 10, 10, 1)

images = tf.convert_to_tensor(image.astype(np.float32))

filter_size = 3
sobel_x = tf.constant([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]], tf.float32)
sobel_x_filter = tf.reshape(sobel_x, [3, 3, 1, 1])

image_patches = tf.extract_image_patches(images,
                                         [1, filter_size, filter_size, 1],
                                         [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1],
                                         padding='SAME')


actual = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(image_patches, tf.reshape(sobel_x_filter, [9])), 3, keep_dims=True)
expected = tf.nn.conv2d(images, sobel_x_filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(expected - actual))
```

This gives you `0.0` as they are equivalent. This does not need a reverse function.

**edit**:

> As I understand from the TensorFlow docs, that is what's done
>   internally with tf.nn.conv2d as well.

Nope, not really. TF on the GPU for example rely on CuDNN which is a more [complex beast](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bffa3e10bf4886f03a68f7e93ba39c91d447f101/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc#L2107-L2179) (winograd, ptx, ...). Only in some circumstances it uses the `im2col` approach like [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/982549ea3423df4270ff154e5c764beb43d472da/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops_using_gemm.cc#L304-L307) on CPU and the quantized version [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/982549ea3423df4270ff154e5c764beb43d472da/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantized_conv_ops.cc#L198).